# Would like to programmatically popup the Worklight/MobileFirst Settings panel

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

In the previous version of Worklight 6.1, I was able to add a link to my login screen that would popup the Worklight Settings native panel when users clicked it.

This helped us support Android devices that didn't have a physical Menu button, and allowed our users to check their Worklight Server connection settings.

I called this method:
WL.App.__showWLPreferences();

In MobileFirst 6.3, this API seems to have been removed.  Is there a way to accomplish this in 6.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WL.App.__showWLPreferences` is undocumented and internal; you probably should not have been able to use it... anyway - not supported.

Starting MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3 there there are new API methods to get and set the MFP Server URL during runtime. See the following blog post for an example: [Changing the Server URL during runtime](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/).

Basically:

1. `WL.App.getServerUrl(getServerURLSuccess, getServerURLFailure);`
2. `WL.App.setServerUrl(serverURL, setServerURLSuccess, setServerURLFailure);`